# Походження фразеологізму "гнути кирпу"

Tags: фразеологізми

І Маша в опрічному житлі вже не так здорово ***гнула кирпу*** перед наймичками й наймитами; вона оговталась, оббулася в чужій оселі, вже не так бундючилась перед сільськими слугами (*Нечуй-Левицький*)

> **[Гнути кирпу](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2344-gnuty-kyrpu.html)** - перед ким, у ролі прис. – пишатися, зазнаватися, хизуватися.

Яке походження даного фразеологізму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Додам до [цієї](/a/4862) відповіді, що, по-моєму, добре пояснює варіант [«задирати кирпу/носа»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29002&page=961), ще про слово [«гнути»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18961&page=648).

Здається, «гнути» позначає не лише буквально «робити зігнутим», а й щось на зразок «вести/просувати». Принаймні, ми бачимо його в таких висловах:

- гнути бандигу;
- гнути всячину/дурниці/небилиці;
- гнути козиря;
- гнути лінію;
- гнути ціну.

Тобто, здається, «гнути кирпу» поповнює множину виразів, де «гнути» позначає не буквально «робити зігнутим» — як от у «гнути коліна», «гнути спину», «гнути шию» — а щось на зразок «вести/просувати».

Answer (score 2):

Значення фразеологізма "Гнути кирпу" - пишатися, зазнаватися, хизуватися (джерело). Що ж означає слово "кирпа"? [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kyrpa) дає таке визначення: "Короткий, задертий догори ніс". Тобто, цей фразеологізм - це те саме, що й "задерти носа", та й справді, досить часто можна побачити як гордовиті люди ходять із задертими догори носами. Очевидно, що якісь люди це помітили і так і з'явився даний фразеологізм.

І тут складно говорити про якесь конкретне походження як ото "ахілесова п'ята" чи "троянський кінь", які походять із давньогрецьких міфів.